# How to parse an array inside a string into a javascript arrray

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript

I have a string received from a database call as follows:

```
"[{'url':'https://www.example.com/','category':'popular'},{'url':'https://example2.com/','category':'new'}]"
```

I would like to parse the string into a typescript/JS array so that it is as follows:

```
[
   {'url':'https://www.example.com/','category':'popular'}, 
   {'url':'https://example2.com/','category':'new'}
]
```

How can I go about doing this? JSON.parse won't work as the string does not resemble a stringified JSON. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no strings in it containing `'`, you can replace all occurrences of the single quote with double quotes, then you can parse it:

```js
const str = "[{'url':'https://www.example.com/','category':'popular'},{'url':'https://example2.com/','category':'new'}]";

const arr = JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g,'"'));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Just curious: What would you do to handle inner `'` characters? Say you have "Joe's Bar" in one of the fields.

Comment: @kol: Then the regex would have to get a lot more complex, as it would have to consider word boundaries, or look for single quotes next to JSON "delimiters" like `[]{}:,`

Answer (score 1):

Replace single quotes with double quotes then `JSON.parse`

```js
JSON.parse(
"[{'url':'https://www.example.com/','category':'popular'},{'url':'https://example2.com/','category':'new'}]"
.replace(/\'/g, '"')
)
```